# Conditional Probability or Independent events?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

There are 7 charitable donors at a gala - 6 "typical" donors and 1 "generous" donor. Every time a "typical" charitable donor is approached for money, she/he will donate (with equal probability) either \$0, \$1, \$2, \$4, or \$8. Every time the "generous" charitable donor is approached, she/he will always give \$8. You and your friend approach the same randomly selected charitable donor and both ask for money, and you both receive \$8. What is the probability that the charitable donor is the "generous" one?

How should I approach this? I am fairly new at probability. The way I was thinking is that the 2 friends statement is given just for confusion because the event of selecting "Generous" donor given that you get $8 would have nothing to do with you or your friend. Am I thinking right?

Comment: You will need to use Bayes theorem, where G represents asking the generous donor and E represents getting an eight dollar donation from two independent requests.

Comment: @MatthewDaly Thank you for the response. I did exactly that, the part where I am stuck is, does the probability get affected since there are 2 people (me and my friend) asking. Or should the probability be the same irrespective of the number of people asking the same person for donation?

Comment: I would say if you and your friend both got an \$8 donation from a typical donor that $P(E|G^C)=1/25$.  Intuitively, the fact that you both got \$8 should make it more likely that the donor was the generous one, and this calculation would make that explicit.

Comment: @MatthewDaly so does this solution look sensible?

P(G/E) = (P(E/G) * P(G)) / P(E)

where P(E/G) = 1 (since the generous donor always gives $8. 
P(G) = 1/7 (Since 1 generous donor amongst 7 donors
and P(E) = ((6/7)*(1/5) + (1/7)*(1/1))

Comment: I think you want 1/25 instead of 1/5 for the reasons I noted above, but otherwise that's just what I got.  Good job!

Comment: @MatthewDaly Thank you, that is exactly what I tried! Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ represent the event that it was the generous donor who was approached, and $E$ represent the event of getting an \$8 contribution from the donor from two different requests.  We are given that $P(G)=1/7$, $P(E|G)=1$, and we can infer that $P(E|G^C)=1/25$ (since a typical donor has five equally likely donations). From this, we can calculate $$P(E)=P(E|G)P(G)+P(E|G^C)P(G^C)=\frac {1}{7}\cdot 1+\frac{6}{7}\cdot\frac{1}{25}=\frac{31}{175}$$
and from here Bayes' Theorem says $$P(G|E)=\frac{P(E|G)P(G)}{P(E)}=\frac{(1/7)\cdot1}{31/175}=\frac{25}{31}$$